# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdf in position 100: invalid continuation byte when writing shapefile in geopandas

Tags: python, arcgis, geopandas

there are hundreds of cases in the form that reading csv-files need to be encoded differently.

Here, it´s different. I want to write a GeoDataFrame to a shapefile in ArcGIS.`

```
df = pd.read_excel("path.xlsx")
df['geometry']  = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df.lon, df.lat)]
dfout = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df,  geometry=df['geometry'])    
dfout.crs= "EPSG:4326"
dfout.to_file('path.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

Does anyone know how I can change the encoding when writing here? Or is it something else?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You seem to be working on Windows. Which version? And by any chance does your user folder name contain non English characters?

Comment: yes, windows 10. no my user folder name is johak (shouldn´t haven hidden it)

Comment: Actually, my mistake, I was thinking about the path of your file, the one on the G drive. If I am reading the stack trace you provided correctly, the issues occurs  when opening the file, so I thought this might be the result of how Windows handles non English path names. But I may be wrong. Try writing output somewhere else, with a simpler path and see if that works.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried that without success so far. So this is independent of the actual data in the geodataframe?

Comment: If changing the path did not help, then I was wrong and the error is else where. I have not worked with Excel for a long time, but you should check if there is a way to set character encoding on the Excel file (From Excel it self). Make sure it is UTF-8 Unicode and not some Windows codepage.

Comment: No, the error was that there were column names with special characters which i had overlooked. Thanks for your help again.

Answer (score 2):

Solved. Forgot about the following issue:

The column names in ArcGIS cannot include special characters such as ':' or '(' etc.